# Insert code makes no insert php

Tags: php

I have a poke-like application and it doesn't seem to be inserting into the table 'pokes'.

Despite my code looking and seeming fine, it doesnt seem to be showing any sign?
Any ideas?

```
if (@$_POST['poke']) {
  $check_if_poked = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pokes WHERE user_to='$username' AND user_from='$added_by'");
$num_poke_found = mysql_num_rows($check_if_poked);
if ($num_poke_found == 1) {
 echo "Come on! Give the guy a chance!";
  }
 else
 if ($username == $cookie) {
 echo "You cannot Jab yourself.";
 }
 else
  { $poke_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokes VALUES ('', '$cookie', '$username')") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
 echo "$username has been jabbed.";
  }
```

}

Comment: Where to begin… Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you would use `AND` rather than `&&`.

```
SELECT * FROM pokes WHERE user_to='$username' AND user_from='$added_by'
```

For the insert, you need to specify the columns to add

```
INSERT INTO pokes (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ('A', 'B')
```

To further debug, try [checking for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)...

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I have added a bit for the INSERT now too.

Comment: I've added an example from the PHP docs about checking for errors - this can be invaluable for finding problems with queries. Do you get any errors back?

Comment: Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: Can you `echo` your query so I can see exactly what SQL you are running? i.e. echo 'INSERT INTO....' exactly as you have it in your code?